# UI for node.js based desktop application

Tags: gui, node.js, user-interface

I understand that node.js is a server side javascript. I want to write a desktop application using node.js. What would be the best tool to build a UI for this application/ what languges frameworks do people usually use to build a GUI for node.js app.

Comment: While Node.js is cross platform not all of GUI libraries are; hence what are your target operating systems?

Comment: by the way [Node package manager](https://www.npmjs.org/browse/keyword/gui) probably will have something for you.

Comment: Haven't really thought about the target operating system but It would be good to have it run on all the platforms. Webkit seems to be doing it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### [NW.js (formerly node-webkit)](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js)

You can write desktop apps using websites (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) while retaining access to all Node.JS features and APIs.

Quoting its [readme](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/blob/master/README.md#introduction) on GitHub:

> NW.js is an app runtime based on  Chromium  and  node.js . You can write native apps in HTML and JavaScript with NW.js. It also lets you call Node.js modules directly from the DOM and enables a new way of writing native applications with all Web technologies.

Features (also quoting from the [readme](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/blob/master/README.md#introduction)):

> - Apps written in modern HTML5, CSS3, JS and WebGL.
> - Complete support for Node.js APIs and all its third party modules.
> - Good performance: Node and WebKit runs in the same thread: Function calls are made straightforward; objects are in the same heap and can
>     just reference each other;
> - Easy to package and distribute apps.
> - Available on Linux, Mac OSX and Windows

Comment: node-webkit has been renamed NW.js

Answer (score 5):

### 2016 Update

There are few options for writing GUI apps in Node:

- [**AppJS**](http://appjs.com/) - the oldest one, not actively developed, recommends NW.js or Electron
- [**NW.js**](http://nwjs.io/) - [previously known as node-webkit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nwjs-general/V1FhvfaFIzQ/720xKVd0jNkJ), sponsored by Intel and Gnor Tech, used in Intel XDK, WhatsApp for Desktop and [many others apps](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-nw.js)
- [**Brackets Shell**](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell#readme)
  by Adobe, a [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)-based application shell for the [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) editor, not really meant for use in anything other than Brackets, but people use it for other projects and there are some tutorials online
- [**Electron**](http://electron.atom.io/) by GitHub - [previously known as the Atom Shell](http://electron.atom.io/blog/2015/04/23/electron)
  originally created for the [Atom editor](https://atom.io/), used by Atom, Slack, Visual Studio Code, Ionic Lab, Light Table, WordPress.com, Google Play Music Desktop Player, Yeoman and [many other apps](http://electron.atom.io/apps/) - **([the 1.0 just released on May 11, 2016](http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/05/11/electron-1-0))**

Answer (score 0):

Electron can be used for it. [You can check it out here](https://www.electronjs.org/)
It's all by HTML CSS and JS
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There's a project called [NodeGUI](https://hibbard.eu/node-gui/), which is based on Qode. It allows developing applications using the QT toolkit. If you've used PyQT/PySide, you should be at home with this.

NodeGUI is still under active development (not recommended for production) and might not contain all QT widgets/functionality.