# SDK for creatingHtml5 desktop apps

Tags: gratis, linux, software-development, desktop-client, sdk

Well this is a very simple question:

- Tidesk SDK is dead, last commit on github was two years ago
- Appjs is dead and they said so on github, they said we should use Deskshell, I can't do so since it's not available on Linux, I have appjs installed but don't want to use it
- Ubuntu SDK seems awesome, but not cross platform so I don't really want to use it, I have it installed
- Mozilla Prism and Chromeless rested in peace too

You understand my question by now but I have to list my requirements so:

- free, not necessarily open source SDK to develop html5 native, cross platform apps
- Maintained and actively developed, well at least not dead
- Easy to package and this is the most important point guys, easy to package for linux distros, I don't care about windows and mac, at least for now. It doesn't have to be `.deb`, in fact I would like to create executable files that would run anywhere `file.sh` would do. If you used appjs, you would understand why packaging is a big deal for me
- If I can create mobile apps using the sdk, that would be a plus but not important right now

Comment: Have a look at a [former answer of mine about `node-webkit`](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3257/583).